# How limited can I make my personal information on PayPal?

Tags: paypal

I want to use my PayPal.Me to accept payments for commissions, but I do not want my full name displayed on it. Is there any way to limit what name it displays?

On the PayPal.Me page, it displays my First Name, Last Name, Address City, and Address State. Is there any way to reduce the amount of information? Such as, switching the last name to just being the first initial for example?

Comment: This may sound like a silly suggestion, but have you asked PayPal?

Comment: @dwizum I tried last night, but customer support was closed for the night. I asked here as I wondered if I could get an answer in the time I could not from them. That being said, I do intend on asking them again once I leave campus for the day.

Comment: Set up a business profile. It'll show the name of the business.

Comment: @ceejayoz That is something I considered, though I do not really know or understand the legal implications of using a business account. I did contact customer support however, and got a method that fits what I need it to be, specifically invoices.

Comment: I would not want to send money to such a person.  It looks scammy to someone who does not know you.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot hide this information. You can enter other data there. But then the goods will be sent to the wrong address if you pay somewhere with PayPal.

Answer (score -1):

The simple answer is **No**, PayPal will not let you do anything like that.

It's highly regulated and highly non-anonymous.

Comment: The regulations you refer to require PayPal to know details of their bank customers; they don't require PayPal to make that information available to the general public.

Comment: ?  The many regs paypal exist under, mean that, (in a word) PayPal will not allow anonymous or shielded accounts.

Comment: They can't be anonymous to *PayPal*. It's PayPal's decision to make names/addresses of sellers available to buyers, not a regulation.